# Wifi Device Not Ready Ubuntu 16.04 HP

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager

Wifi not working on my HP laptop.

I have tried
 `sudo systemctl restart network-manager.`

It doesn't work.

Here are output of few commands:

`nishanthr@vision:~$ lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 130
    Region 0: I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Region 2: Memory at b1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>`

` nishanthr@vision:~$ iwconfig

```
eno1      no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

lo        no wireless extensions. `
```

`nishanthr@vision:~$ lshw -c network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network

       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: 80:ce:62:10:82:02
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.0.104 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b1104000-b1104fff memory:b1100000-b1103fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: b0:52:16:ba:f5:8f
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723de driverversion=4.15.0-36-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:130 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1000000-b100ffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.`

`nishanthr@vision:~$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no`

`nishanthr@vision:~$ dmesg | grep rtl
[   28.873013] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000d lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8723
[   28.873015] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723d_config.bin
[   29.090626] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723d_config.bin failed with error -2
[   29.090639] Bluetooth: Necessary config file rtl_bt/rtl8723d_config.bin not found
[   29.090659] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723d_fw.bin
[   29.090682] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723d_fw.bin failed with error -2
[   29.090683] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load rtl_bt/rtl8723d_fw.bin
[   29.091999] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000d lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8723
[   29.092010] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723d_config.bin
[   29.092016] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723d_config.bin failed with error -2
[   29.092017] Bluetooth: Necessary config file rtl_bt/rtl8723d_config.bin not found
[   29.092019] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723d_fw.bin
[   29.092024] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723d_fw.bin failed with error -2
[   29.092025] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load rtl_bt/rtl8723d_fw.bin
[   30.571336] rtlwifi: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   30.571375] rtlwifi: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   31.228154] rtl8723de: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723defw.bin
[   31.270566] rtl8723de 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for rtlwifi/rtl8723defw.bin failed with error -2
[   31.270567] rtlwifi: Selected firmware is not available
[   31.295167] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   31.295363] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[   31.512571] rtl8723de 0000:02:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0`

It'll ge great if someone can help.
Thanks.

Comment: DISABLED usually means that the hardware switch is set to disable to wireless radios. Confirm: `rfkill list all`

Comment: I've posted the above command's output to my question now.

Comment: Let's dig a bit deeper. Please add: `dmesg | grep rtl`

Comment: Sure.I've edited my question and added the output of the above command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing firmware for the wifi device, to fix this, in terminal do

```
cd /lib/firmware/rtlwifi
sudo wget https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/raw/extended/firmware/rtlwifi/rtl8723defw.bin
```

Then reboot